# Camera position in world coordinate from cv::solvePnP

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv, computer-vision, pose-estimation

I have a calibrated camera (intrinsic matrix and distortion coefficients) and I want to know the camera position knowing some 3d points and their corresponding points in the image (2d points).

I know that `cv::solvePnP` could help me, and after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444433/calculate-camera-world-position-with-opencv-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515200/python-opencv-solvepnp-yields-wrong-translation-vector?lq=1) I understand that I the outputs of solvePnP `rvec` and `tvec` are the rotation and translation of the object in camera coordinate system.

So I need to find out the camera rotation/translation in the world coordinate system.

From the links above it seems that the code is straightforward, in python:

```
found,rvec,tvec = cv2.solvePnP(object_3d_points, object_2d_points, camera_matrix, dist_coefs)
rotM = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)[0]
cameraPosition = -np.matrix(rotM).T * np.matrix(tvec)
```

I don't know python/numpy stuffs (I'm using C++) but this does not make a lot of sense to me:

- rvec, tvec output from solvePnP are 3x1 matrix, 3 element vectors
- cv2.Rodrigues(rvec) is a 3x3 matrix
- cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)[0] is a 3x1 matrix, 3 element vectors
- cameraPosition is a 3x1 * 1x3 matrix multiplication that is a.. 3x3 matrix. how can I use this in opengl with simple `glTranslatef` and `glRotate` calls?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If with "world coordinates" you mean "object coordinates", you have to get the inverse transformation of the result given by the pnp algorithm.

There is a trick to invert transformation matrices that allows you to save the inversion operation, which is usually expensive, and that explains the code in Python. Given a transformation `[R|t]`, we have that `inv([R|t]) = [R'|-R'*t]`, where `R'` is the transpose of `R`. So, you can code (not tested):

```
cv::Mat rvec, tvec;
solvePnP(..., rvec, tvec, ...);
// rvec is 3x1, tvec is 3x1

cv::Mat R;
cv::Rodrigues(rvec, R); // R is 3x3

R = R.t();  // rotation of inverse
tvec = -R * tvec; // translation of inverse

cv::Mat T = cv::Mat::eye(4, 4, R.type()); // T is 4x4
T( cv::Range(0,3), cv::Range(0,3) ) = R * 1; // copies R into T
T( cv::Range(0,3), cv::Range(3,4) ) = tvec * 1; // copies tvec into T

// T is a 4x4 matrix with the pose of the camera in the object frame
```

**Update:** Later, to use `T` with OpenGL you have to keep in mind that the axes of the camera frame differ between OpenCV and OpenGL.

OpenCV uses the reference usually used in computer vision: X points to the right, Y down, Z to the front (as in [this image](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/gifs/extrinsic.gif)). The frame of the camera in OpenGL is: X points to the right, Y up, Z to the back (as in the left hand side of [this image](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/gl_projectionmatrix01.png)). So, you need to apply a rotation around X axis of 180 degrees. The formula of this rotation matrix is in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations).

```
// T is your 4x4 matrix in the OpenCV frame
cv::Mat RotX = ...; // 4x4 matrix with a 180 deg rotation around X
cv::Mat Tgl = T * RotX; // OpenGL camera in the object frame
```

These transformations are always confusing and I may be wrong at some step, so take this with a grain of salt.

Finally, take into account that matrices in OpenCV are stored in row-major order in memory, and OpenGL ones, in column-major order.

Comment: seems to work, I get the angles for `glRotatef` with a formula taken from this: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToEuler/index.htm and then normal conversion from radials to degree. But but if I plug those values in opengl I still get a wrong camera rotation (rotation X is something like 45° wrong) and slightly wrong translation..

Comment: That may be due to the fact that the camera frame in OpenCV and OpenGL are different. Check my extended answer.

Comment: yes I know the difference in the order of matrix in memory between opencv and opengl. And I also have to flip the y and z axis ( => use opencv y as opengl z, and use opencv z as opengl y)

Comment: almost near! the result are coherent with several trials. It seems to me that there is an error of 45° on X axis (that could be some difference in the frame between opencv and opengl that I don't understand) and of 10° on y angle (that I don't know how to interpret)

Comment: Are you sure the axes are as you say? I think they are as in my example, but I might be wrong. Check also trat the projection parameters of the camera are the same in opencv and opengl.

Comment: ok so, it was an error somewhereelse. I have to rotateY(180) and rotateZ(180), I haven't understand exactly why but it seems to work very well. Thank you a lot for the complete answer!

Comment: (anyway it seems working well but I'm looking for a way to numerically test it, if you have suggestion, are welcome!)

Comment: @ChronoTrigger do you know where the OpenCV image frame is centered? The image center or the top-left corner? When you give 2d image points to solvePnp, are those 2d coordinates related to the image center or the top-left corner?

Comment: @manatttta Use image coordinates starting at the top-left corner, because the camera calibration already contains the coordinates of the optical center. You may use any frame of reference other than the top-left corner by modifying the calibration parameters accordingly.

Comment: For me works not rotate camera for 180 degrees, but I rotated whole scene around X axis and left camera pose matrix untouched.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to turn it into a standard 4x4 pose matrix specifying the position of your camera.  Use rotM as the top left 3x3 square, tvec as the 3 elements on the right, and 0,0,0,1 as the bottom row

```
pose = [rotation   tvec(0)
        matrix     tvec(1)
        here       tvec(2)
        0  , 0, 0,  1]
```

then invert it (to get pose of camera instead of pose of world)