# OpenCV + OpenGL: proper camera pose using solvePnP

Tags: ios, opencv, opengl-es, glkit

I've got problem with obtaining proper camera pose from iPad camera using OpenCV.

I'm using custom made 2D marker (based on [AruCo library](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26) ) - I want to render 3D cube over that  marker using OpenGL.

In order to recieve camera pose I'm using solvePnP function from OpenCV.

According to [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637494/camera-position-in-world-coordinate-from-cvsolvepnp) I'm doing it like this:

```cpp
cv::solvePnP(markerObjectPoints, imagePoints, [self currentCameraMatrix], _userDefaultsManager.distCoeffs, rvec, tvec);

tvec.at<double>(0, 0) *= -1; // I don't know why I have to do it, but translation in X axis is inverted

cv::Mat R;
cv::Rodrigues(rvec, R); // R is 3x3

R = R.t();  // rotation of inverse
tvec = -R * tvec; // translation of inverse

cv::Mat T(4, 4, R.type()); // T is 4x4
T(cv::Range(0, 3), cv::Range(0, 3)) = R * 1; // copies R into T
T(cv::Range(0, 3), cv::Range(3, 4)) = tvec * 1; // copies tvec into T
double *p = T.ptr<double>(3);
p[0] = p[1] = p[2] = 0;
p[3] = 1;
```

camera matrix & dist coefficients are coming from *findChessboardCorners* function, *imagePoints* are manually detected corners of marker (you can see them as green square in the video posted below), and *markerObjectPoints* are manually hardcoded points that represents marker corners:

```cpp
markerObjectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3d(-6, -6, 0));
markerObjectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3d(6, -6, 0));
markerObjectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3d(6, 6, 0));
markerObjectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3d(-6, 6, 0));
```

Because marker is 12 cm long in real world, I've chosed the same size in the for easier debugging.

As a result I'm recieving 4x4 matrix T, that I'll use as ModelView matrix in OpenCV.
Using GLKit drawing function looks more or less like this:

```cpp
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // preparations
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    float aspect = fabsf(self.bounds.size.width / self.bounds.size.height);
    effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(39), aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

    // set modelViewMatrix
    float mat[16] = generateOpenGLMatFromFromOpenCVMat(T);
    currentModelMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeWithArrayAndTranspose(mat);
    effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = currentModelMatrix;

    [effect prepareToDraw];

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); // draw previously prepared cube
}
```

I'm not rotating everything for 180 degrees around X axis (as it was mentioned in previously linked article), because I doesn't look as necessary.

The problem is that it doesn't work! Translation vector looks OK, but X and Y rotations are messed up :(

I've recorded a video presenting that issue:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMNBT5H7-os

I've tried almost everything (including inverting all axises one by one), but nothing actually works.

What should I do? How should I properly display that 3D cube? Translation / rotation vectors that come from solvePnP are looking reasonable, so I guess that I can't correctly map these vectors to OpenGL matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Djo1509 from http://answers.opencv.org/ I've found out that the problem was unnecessary transposed rotation matrix R matrix used as part of matrix T, and unnecessary *tvec = -R * tvec* operation.

For more info look [there](http://answers.opencv.org/question/23089/opencv-opengl-proper-camera-pose-using-solvepnp/)