# Transformation matrix from 2D to 3D in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, 2d, transformation

I have some 2D points set (X,Y) corresponding to a 3D points set (X,Y,Z).
2D points were captured from camera and 3D points were the real coordinate according to world base. I want to find the transformation matrix between them, that is to say, how to convert other 2D points to 3D points.

I have try getPespectiveTransform function, but it didnt work in this problem.

How can I write a regression to find this transform matrix ?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera

Comment: Though it should be noted that a point in an image corresponds to a ray in 3D space, so you'll haver get a "transform" between the two...You can (essentially) find the ray the 3D point would intercept and map that to an into 2D space, but it is non-trivial to go the other way.

Comment: I mean that I have two points set, one is 2d (x,y) and another is 3d(x,y,z). I want to find the relationship between those two set, and i dont use any camera calibration to trans.

Comment: Sorry for my poor english

Comment: This seems like a problem for `solvePnP` (see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp)). You need to know the camera matrix and intrinsics coefficients though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `solvePnP` of `OpenCV`, it gives you rotation and translation matrix. In this answer you can see in more detail:
[Camera position in world coordinate from cv::solvePnP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637494/camera-position-in-world-coordinate-from-cvsolvepnp)