# Displaying camera orientation using matlab from the camera calibration result with OpenCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, matlab-cvst, calibration

I'm using OpenCV's camera calibration function, I have 34 images of the checkerboard on a turntable, taken from a static camera. The camera position from the initial tvec is approximately correct, however the rvec is totally wrong. I ploted the orientation in matlab to indicate the problem.

[image: orientation plot]

The formula I used should be correct like,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637494/camera-position-in-world-coordinate-from-cvsolvepnp).

My question is why these orientations are wrong ? is this normal for the calibration algorithm?
Matlab uses Z as the up axis, could this be my visualization code problem ?

Thanks.

**Update:**

I put my plot code here, I suspect it has the problem.

```
function drawCameraPoses(rvec, tvec)

if (size(tvec,2) ~= 3 || size(tvec,1) <= 0)
    disp('tvec must contain 3 columns and greater than 0 row') ;
    exit ;
end

if (size(rvec) ~= size(tvec))
    disp('rvec must be at the same size of the tvec.') ;
end


%plot camera positions
figure ;
%watch out xyz order
plot3(tvec(:,1), tvec(:,3), tvec(:,2),'r+') ;
hold on ;
grid on ;

plotrange = [max(tvec);min(tvec)] ;
disp(plotrange)
xyrange = [max([plotrange(1,1),plotrange(1,3)]) ; min([plotrange(2,1),plotrange(2,3)])];
disp(xyrange)
plotscaleFactor = 1.5 ;

xlim([xyrange(2) - abs(xyrange(2))*(plotscaleFactor - 1.0), xyrange(1) + abs(xyrange(1))*(plotscaleFactor - 1.0)]) ;
ylim([xyrange(2) - abs(xyrange(2))*(plotscaleFactor - 1.0), xyrange(1) + abs(xyrange(1))*(plotscaleFactor - 1.0)]) ;
zlim([plotrange(2,2) - abs(plotrange(2,2)) * (plotscaleFactor - 1.0), plotrange(1,2) + abs(plotrange(1,2)) * (plotscaleFactor - 1.0)]) ;

%plot camera orientation

for i = 1 : size(rvec,1)
    [x,y,z] = getEndPoint(tvec(i,:),rvec(i,:)) ;
    line([tvec(i,1), x],[tvec(i,3),z],[tvec(i,2),y],'Color','r');
end


end

function [x,y,z] = getEndPoint(t,r)
length = 50 ;
unitR = r / norm(r) ;
unitR = unitR * length ;
x = t(1) + unitR(1) ;
y = t(2) + unitR(2) ;
z = t(3) + unitR(3) ;
end
```

Comment: What are you plotting> what is x,y,z inn that 3D plot?

Comment: If the rvec from OpenCV is [r0,r1,r2], position tvec is [t0,t1,t2] , in the 3D plot, position is [t0,t2,t1], then I normalized the rvec into [r0',r1',r2'], so the orientation vector would be [r0', r2', r1'], I just ploted line segments starts from [t0,t2,t1], end with [t0+r0'*length, t2+r2' * length, t1+r1'*length]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the output rvec and tvec should form the transformation matrix rather than simply coordinate assignment. So inspired from the [calibration toolbox](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/).

The code to display the camera poses would be,

```
function drawCameraPoses(rvec, tvec, flag)

if (size(tvec,2) ~= 3 || size(tvec,1) <= 0)
    disp('tvec must contain 3 columns and greater than 0 row') ;
    exit ;
end

if (size(rvec) ~= size(tvec))
    disp('rvec must be at the same size of the tvec.') ;
end

if ~flag
    %raw rvec tvec
    for i = 1:size(tvec,1)
        rotM = rodrigues(rvec(i,:)) ;
        tvec(i,:) = -rotM'* tvec(i,:)' ;
        rvec(i,:) = rodrigues(rotM') ;
    end
end

%plot camera positions
figure ;
%watch out xyz order
plot3(tvec(:,1), tvec(:,2), tvec(:,3),'r+') ;
hold on ;
grid on ;

xlim([-1 1]) ;
ylim([-1 1]) ;
zlim([-1 1]) ;

%plot camera orientation
baseSymbol = 0.2 * [0 1 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 1 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 1] ;
for i = 1 : size(rvec,1)
   %rotM already transposed
   rotM = rodrigues(rvec(i,:)) ;
   baseK = rotM * baseSymbol + tvec(i,:)' * ones(1,6) ;
   plot3(baseK(1,:),baseK(2,:), baseK(3,:),'-b') ;
end


end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For visualizing the camera orientation try the [plotCamera](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/plotcamera.html) function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

While you are at it, try the [Camera Calibrator app](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html).