# use SolvePnP Rotation and translation vector in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, matrix

I'm working on an AR program. I have done this steps:

- Detect corners of a chess board with OpenCV
- Use SolvePNP to find rvec and tvec
- Apply Rodrigues on rvec to get R_mat
- Use `hconcat(R_mat, tvec, P);` to concatenate R_mat and tvec to get Projection matrix
- Apply `decomposeProjectionMatrix` on P to get new translation,T2, vector and eulerAngles

now my problem is in translation vectors just tvec[2] or translation over Z-axis is correct
and in rotations again in Euler Angles (from  `decomposeProjectionMatrix`) just eulerAngles[2] or rotation around z-axis is correct.
I don't know hoa can I get Translation and Rotation related to X-axis and Y-axis correctly.
I'm gonna use these in OpenGL to Augment a cube on the pattern.
In my code, result of translation over X and Y axis is very larger than windows size; and rotaion around  X and Y axis are very small and always near the zero (less than 0.0001)

Any Idea how to get correct meaningful T and R?
P.S : I'm using an Identity matrix as camera matrix and zero matrix for dist coeff matrix.

Comment: did you find http://answers.opencv.org/question/23089/opencv-opengl-proper-camera-pose-using-solvepnp/ during your research? They say that for example some axis might be inverted.

Comment: Yes I tried it but did not worked. it's not a negative or positive sign problem. the result I get is really irrelevant. my window size is 640X480 but I get a translation like 6000 ! and also rotations of Y and X is always zero...

Comment: the translation is in 3D coordinates, isn't it? So it isn't directly related to the 2D image coordinates. Or am I missing something? In fact I'm not sure why you are using `decomposeProjectionMatrix`? What exactly do you want to achieve there? Imho you should: Compute and compose model-view matrix from solvePnP and use that for projection in openGL more or less directly?!

Comment: I tried to found out rvec and tvec more deeply. I reprojeced the pattern 3d points from SolvePNP with rvec and tvec and the result was really good! It seems that OpenCV uses a format that I can not Understand. In another attempt I manually set a tvec and rvec and projected a set of points . result was really weird with OpenCV. with a rvec=[1 0 0] and tvec=[ 0 0 0] the points were rotated about 89 degree and for rvec=[10 0  0] the've been rotated 89 degree again! just a little more, say 89.2 degree. what is the problem?

Comment: Thancks. But can you be more specific? I'm gonna doing put a 3d cube on a chess board pattern (AR program with 3d model) like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmDdfmrZqgA

Comment: I didnt try it myself yet, but don't these two links try to do exactly the same? http://answers.opencv.org/question/23089/opencv-opengl-proper-camera-pose-using-solvepnp/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637494/camera-position-in-world-coordinate-from-cvsolvepnp

Comment: and in openCV doc there is a hint: An example of how to use solvePNP for planar augmented reality can be found at opencv_source_code/samples/python2/plane_ar.py I didn't have a look at the python code yet, but maybe that gives you more hints.